# JSON passed through Laravel view only accessible through listener function in JS script

Tags: javascript, json, laravel-5, google-maps-api-3

I'm having an issue accessing a json file from a js script in a Laravel project.

I am using the Google maps API to add markers to a map, which are all currently hard-coded because I can only seem to access the json from within a listener function.

I am fully able to access my json through the placeMarker click listener, but when i try to make the "otherPlace" using json values, the values cannot be found. Not sure what's going on here.

Sorry for the likely noob question but I am stumped and couldn't find any similar questions.

Map script Example:

```
function myMap() {
    var mapProp= {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(44.5458062,-83.54936229999996),
        zoom:8,
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

    var place = new google.maps.LatLng(44.453,-83.45773609999998);
    var placeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: place});

    var otherPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(json.locations[4].lat,json.locations[4].lng);
    var otherPlaceMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: otherPlace});

    placeMarker.setMap(map);
    otherPlaceMarker.setMap(map);

    placeMarker.addListener('click', function() {
        map.setZoom(13);
        map.setCenter(placeMarker.getPosition());
        console.log(json.locations[5].address);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            //content: json.locations[5].name + "\r\nAddress: " + json.locations[5].address
        });

        infowindow.setContent(
            "<p>" + json.locations[5].name + "<br />" + json.locations[5].address + "<br/> <a href='#'>Get Directions</a> </p>"
        );
        infowindow.open(map,placeMarker);
    }); 
}
```

In my controller I grab the json file and pass it to the view

```
public function locations() {
        $path = storage_path() . "/json/locations.json"; 
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true); 
        return view('home/locations', compact('json'));
}
```

In my locations.blade.php I add the map script and pass the json to javascript

```
@section('scripts')
<script src="/js/locationsMap.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ env('APP_GOOGLE_MAPS') }}&callback=myMap"></script>
<script> 
    var json = {!! json_encode($json) !!};
</script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `var` from `var json` if that doesn't work, put your function below `json = {!! json_encode($json) !!};` and try then

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So it WILL work if i put my whole map script in the script tag under the json encode. Any idea how I can make it work as a separate script?

Comment: Did removing `var` work when your function is in separate script?

Comment: No it didn't but I just figured it out thanks to you. Just needed to change the order of the scripts. Can't believe I didn't try that before. Thank you!

Comment: Ye, I wanted to suggest that, but I figured if you make your `json` variable global it also might work, you just remove `var` to do so :)